# Не подключается расширение CURL в PHP

Tags: curl, php, config

Не может подключиться модуль курл.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
> function curl_init()

Диагностика:

- `get_loaded_extensions()` показывает, что модуль curl не подключен;
- в `php.ini` строчка `extension=php_curl.dll` раскомментирована;
- `php.ini` находится в `c:\windows` (`php_ini_loaded_file()`), в нем и смотрел;
- файл `php_curl.dll` существует и находится в `c:\php\ext`;
- phpinfo показывает `extension_dir = c:\php\ext`;
- файлы `libeay32.dll` и `ssleay32.dll` есть в `system32`;
- при команде `php -m` показывает, что расширение подключилось, а если как модуль апач - не подключается.

Подскажите, куда дальше копать и почему он не подключается?

Система: Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1, Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) PHP/5.6.5

Comment: скорее всего, это разница в версиях

Comment: ну хз, из коробки

Comment: попробуйте startup errors в php.ini включить

Answer (score 1):

Решил. Оказалось, надо добавить папку с php в переменную окружения Path. Багрепорты об этой ошибке:

- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68208
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68047

p.s. Чего только не пробовал вчера, и библиотеку MS Visual C++ переставлял, и ставил обе версии х64 и х86, и проверял зависимости файла php_curl.dll, и пол дня устанавливал обновления системы, из-за нехватки нужных ему ДЛЛок. Ничего из этого не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая ошибка, решил восстановлением оригинального конфига и его новой настройкой.
Подозреваю, что в старом что-то напортачил - запятая не там или три пробела подряд кладут PHP, не знаю.