# Как исправить кодировку сайта в ответ на cURL запрос?

Tags: php

Пожалуйста, помогите победить кодировку.

Проблема следующая, в ответ на curl приходит сайт в котором в meta прописана кодировка windows-1251 из-за этого на сайте отображаются иероглифы.
Данную проблему решил с помощью:

```
$isWinCharset = mb_check_encoding($postResult, "windows-1251");
 if ($isWinCharset) {
    $postResult = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $postResult);
}
```

Теперь если в meta стоит кодировка windows-1251 сайт отображается корректно.
Если в meta стоит кодировка utf-8 сайт отображается корректно.
Обрадовался.
Но вдруг нашел пару сайтов, которые слетели после добавления:

```
$isWinCharset = mb_check_encoding($postResult, "windows-1251");
if ($isWinCharset) {
    $postResult = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $postResult);
}
```

в meta указана кодировка UTF-8 а сайт в результате в иероглифах, пример такого сайта: http://e-qa.ru/autoprodazha

Таких сайтов не много но они есть и очень раздражают, большинство сайтов где в meta UTF-8 работают корректно. Видимо кодировка самого файла у данного сайта e-qa.ru/autoprodazha отличается от указанной в meta из-за этого происходит конфликт.

Помогите разобраться и устранить иероглифы на всех сайтах, кучу методов перепробовал и все взаимоисключающие :(

Код:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $engine_url );
//"identity", "deflate" , "gzip"
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$postResult = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$isWinCharset = mb_check_encoding($postResult, "windows-1251");
if ($isWinCharset) {
    $postResult = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $postResult);
}
     echo $postResult;
```

Comment: Кодировка у данного сайта на самом деле UTF-8, как и указано

Comment: Ссылки, ведущие на сайты с рекламой "продажи воздуха" в ваших вопросах слишком похожи на хитрый спам.

Comment: Нет, это не спам, действительно проблема с кодировкой.

Comment: @MicroRu добавьте, пожалуйста, скрин в каком конкретно месте проблема (иерогрифы).

Comment: Иероглифы везде, даже в title  https://i.gyazo.com/892d3f734a6aba955fc5fae4325c0f9a.png

Comment: Добавил свой код в вопрос. Вот, что еще предлагают для решения https://i.gyazo.com/89d40d0c32fa3d91d2a2347c6c6567f0.png https://i.gyazo.com/ce245825fa3d3e58075247c9f4beaa98.png но там код для python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример определения кодировки страницы по заголовку ответа сервера или через тег meta из тела страницы:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
$engine_url = 'http://e-qa.ru/autoprodazha';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $engine_url );
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$postResult = curl_exec($ch);

// Содержимое полученного заголовка Content-Type
$ctype = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

curl_close($ch);

// Попытка определить кодировку из заголовка ответа или тега meta из тела страницы
$charset = null;
if (($ctype !== null && preg_match('%charset=([\w-]+)%i', $ctype, $matches))
    || preg_match('%<meta[^>]+charset=[\'"]?([\w-]+)%i', $postResult, $matches)) {
    $charset = $matches[1];
}
//var_dump($charset);

if ($charset && strtoupper($charset) !== 'UTF-8') {
    $postResult = iconv($charset, 'UTF-8', $postResult);
}

echo $postResult;
```

Comment: Адреса по https не работают, пример https://infobizzone.ru/akp/

Comment: Вчера на фрилансе заказал скрипт, сделали, у фрилансера на обычном хостинге все сайты работают, у меня иероглифы либо пустая страница http://1fastmoney.ru/1.txt у меня centos6 vps

Comment: https работают но конкретно этот https://infobizzone.ru/akp/ не хочет, включаю var_dump($charset); получаю NULL

Comment: Он же но по http открывается, string(5) "UTF-8"

Comment: @MicroRu, проверил у себя на адресе `https://infobizzone.ru/akp/`. В php 5.4-5.6 все работает нормально. И определение кодировки, и получение страницы. В php 7.0.4 не работает. Ругается на расширения php_curl.dll и php_openssl.dll. Так что скрипт не виноват, виноваты настройки php/расширения.

Comment: Спасибо! Пошел смотреть что у меня с php

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, каким хостингом вы пользуетесь, буду к вам переходить, у себя на vps от ihc.ru все версии php пробовал, все отдают NULL в вашем коде и пустую страницу в коде http://1fastmoney.ru/1.txt при обращении к https://infobizzone.ru/akp/

Comment: @MicroRu, на локальном компьютере проверка была сделана. Установлен UwAmp. Php версии 5.x шли вместе со сборкой, а php 7.0 был установлен отдельно, по этому и думаю, что ssl из-за этого на нем не работает. А вам следует заглянуть в лог ошибок сервера и трясти свою поддержку на счет работы curl с ssl для доступа к https сайтам.

Comment: @MicroRu, результат phpinfo() посмотрите у себя. Должно быть в таблице **curl** - `cURL support  enabled` и ниже в этой же таблице строка `SSL  Yes`. А у себя причину не работы на 7.x наше. Curl отказывается загружаться, хотя и подключен Вот описание проблемы и решение для Windows https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/406046/186083

Comment: Все как вы и сказали https://i.gyazo.com/969bf9db4732007476d6921e2450d76c.png но не работает

Comment: https://yandex.ru/ и гугл по https открываются отлично, конкретно https://infobizzone.ru/akp/ не хочет но открывается по http, скорее всего из-за кодировки

Comment: @MicroRu, если бы проблема была в кодировке, то и по http вы получали бы кашу или пустоту, как по https. **P.S.** В лог ошибок сервера зайдите и посмотрите, какие ошибки там присутствуют.

Comment: нет ошибок в логах, заколдованный круг... Visman как вас можно найти в сети, чтобы написать вам?