# apache не видит intl и curl

Tags: php, apache, apache2

в php -m

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

apache запущен ис под админа... 
В логах апача:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: C:\php\ext\curl (\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd.), C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll (\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd.)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: C:\php\ext\intl (\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd.), C:\php\ext\php_intl.dll (\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd.)) in Unknown on line 0

Переменные path прописаны, после комп был перезагружен - не помогло.

Comment: Возможный дубликат, ознакомьтесь с вопросом(всё ли описаное там - присутствует у вас) и с ответами. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/406046/Не-подключается-расширение-curl-в-php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не подключается расширение CURL в PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/406046/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-curl-%d0%b2-php)

Comment: Это решение не помогло